# Restore question for large files

Tags: recycle-bin

Is it true that if there is a very large file in SharePoint's recycle bin then smaller files will no longer show up within the recycle bin even though they are still there?

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the quota of storage allocated to the recycle bin.

Once the site quota is full the site will not allow any data operations. For example you will not be able to upload new files or delete files. You should go and create more space by increasing quota or clearing recycle bin.